# NativeScript: How to get all files in the camera folder?

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to figure out how to list all files available in the folder, in which Android keeps the pictures taken by the camera.

I was looking at this documentation page:
https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system

I couldn't find anything useful for me here.

Also, i assume that such an operation would require some permission.

Can anybody point me into the right direction? I'm totally new to both Android and NativeScript.

Comment: NativeScript can possibly document only their core modules within framework, for anything beyond that, like features within Android SDK you should refer the Android docs, I believe you are looking for [DIRECTORY_PICTURES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_PICTURES).

Comment: Well i already found that NativeScript has a plugin called nativescript-imagepicker. Thank you anyway :D

Comment: If your purpose was an image picker not to read files specifically in camera, of course it works.

Comment: Manoj, can you explain what to do with this constant further? It seems to just return a string "Pictures". How do i actually "browse" this folder? The image-picker didn't provide the functionality i was looking for...i need to present all images in the gallery - manually.

Comment: You have to use the [file-system module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system) to read files, make sure you have read / write permissions on external storage, you will have to use [nativescript-permissions](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions/) for same.

Comment: Ok, but how do i read this directory using the file-system module? android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
            ).toString() returns the full path to the directory. What can i do with this now?

Comment: Create instance of folder from that path and just read the list of files, you have all appreciate methods documented in the above link.

Comment: Yes thank you, i managed to do so by using fileSystemModule.Folder.fromPath and then getEntities().